# packages aren't install in project's virtual enviroment

Tags: python, django, pip, pycharm

i installed django-ckeditor with pip but it goes to the "/home/def-dev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages" path when i'm trying to create venv manually.

but when i create project with pycharm it goes to the "./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages" path
that this path belong's to internal project's venv .

and this make's unknown for pycharm .

what should i do to make pycharm find packages from "/home/def-dev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages" or when i'm creating venv manually pip save's packages into "./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages" path.

when i create venv manually

```
$ pip3 install django-ckeditor

Requirement already satisfied: django-ckeditor in /home/def-dev/.local/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: django-js-asset>=1.2.2 in /home/def- 
dev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django-ckeditor) (1.2.2)
```

when i create venv with pycharm

```
$ pip3 install django-ckeditor

Requirement already satisfied: django-ckeditor in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: django-js-asset>=1.2.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages 
(from django-ckeditor) (1.2.2)
```

Comment: Activate the virtual environment, then use `python -m pip install`. This ensures you will use `pip` from the virtual environment to install the package.

Comment: in pycharm you can create a venv and add your venv to the project interpreter , once added when u open terminal in pycharm it will automaticaly activate venv and u can use pip to install packages